# Ubunt 14.04 & Python 2.7: How can I solve PIP INSTALL PROBLEM?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I am having problem with pip install on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7

I have tried to uninstall & install python-pip unfortunately it didn't solved my problem.. Any idea how I can fix this issue??

sudo pip install psycopg2-binary

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2-binary
Cleaning up...
Exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
        do_download,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
        self.session,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
        resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 479, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
        return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 562, in urlopen
        body=body, headers=headers)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 145, in connect
        match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(),
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in getpeercert
        for value in get_subj_alt_name(x509)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 94, in get_subj_alt_name
        asn1Spec=general_names)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 825, in __call__
        stGetValueDecoder, self, substrateFun
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 391, in valueDecoder
        r.verifySizeSpec()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 252, in verifySizeSpec
        def verifySizeSpec(self): self._sizeSpec(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
        '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
    ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: ---- TRUNCATED ---
```

Comment: can you install anything else with pip?

Comment: check here - https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3769#issuecomment-421261421

Comment: I can not install any module

Comment: @N.C. ; suggested solution (Install pip From PyPI) in your link solved the problem!!.. Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Tolga easy :) one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [that source](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3769#issuecomment-421261421):
You need to uninstall pip2 and after that install pip2 using PyPI
(Refer 'Install pip From PyPI' section in https://www.howtodojo.com/2016/03/install-use-pip-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run these first?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```